# How to open a URL in batch file that require Username and Password?

Tags: windows, url, browser, batch-file, batch-processing

In the Command Prompt,

I can open a url by `START Http://www.foobar.com`

What if the website require to type in a Username and Password?

as shown in [image: Username Password]

btw the Username is a domain account like foo\bar

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing, we're talking about HTTP Basic authentication? If so, you can use something like

```
START http://username:password@www.foobar.com
```

Just tested, this [does not work on newer versions of Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489/en-us). It works on Firefox and most likely on other browsers. Internet Explorer can save the password though, you'll have to use the dialogue on the page once.

Comment: Does Domain account works in this case? like Start http：//abc\abc:123@www.foobar.com?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never came across this kind of username with HTTP BA so far. As you are accessing the page with the Browser, the login should be handled by the Webserver. For Apache e.g. login data is stored as `username:encrypted_password` somewhere. If the stored username is abc\abc, then it should still work, but if you have such a site at hand, you can simply try ;)

Comment: I'm trying to call a CFM file on the website say www.foobar.com/foobar.cfm  I found the problem is due to File Security which using Integrated Windows authentication. So when I use browser to open the uRL, i can type in the domain account and password.

Comment: Thanks very much Bone-Idle btw.